# Display qTip on input field click and until there is less than 3 chars typed

Tags: jquery, forms, qtip2

As described in title I need to display qtip tooltip when click on input field and if there is more than 2 chars typed then hide qtip

Comment: currently i wasnt been able even display qTip tooltip at all on input element...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to show/hide the qTip based on the length of the input, use this:

```
$('#textbox').qtip();

$("#textbox")
    .bind("focus keyup change", function () {
        $(this).qtip('toggle', ($(this).val().length <= 2));
});
```